# Backbone.js fails to load Tinymce script only when moving through the router

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, tinymce

I am using tinymce to create a rich Textarea, and I am using backbone.js.

The problem is that when i move to that "page" in my router from a previous URL that is on the same site, it just doesn't work.

If i refresh the page with the direct link to that route it works fine. I really don't understand what can go wrong.

Here is the view:

> ```
> var template = function (name) {
>     var source = $('#' + name + '-template').html();
>     return Handlebars.compile(source);
> }; 
>   BT.Common.FormTextArea = Backbone.View.extend({
>     template : template('form-input-textarea'),
>     tagName: 'div',
>     className: "control-group",
>     initialize: function(){
>     },
>     render: function(){
>         console.debug("Render FormTextArea");
>         var html = this.template(this.model.toJSON());
>         this.$el.html(html);    
>         tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'});
>         return this;
>     },
> });
> ```

The template:

> ```
>   <script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="form-input-textarea-template">
>       <label class="control-label" for="message">{{lable}}</label>
>       <div class="controls">
>         <textarea name="msgpost" id="msgpost" cols="50" rows="10">
>             {{text}}  
>         </textarea>
>       </div>
> </script>
> ```

Comment: Did you check the console section for any errors

Comment: No errors. i actually tried to keep a record of the Instance and use it again. Didn't work as well. I solved it by using an Iframe. i will write am answer soon

Answer (score 2):

TinyMCE apparently doesn't like to work on detached nodes. At all.

This setup reproduces your predicament:

```
var v = new BT.Common.FormTextArea({
    model: new Backbone.Model({text: 'init'})
});

v.render().$el.appendTo('body');
```

and an accompanying Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/pCdSy/

A simple workaround would be to provide your view an attached node. For example, assuming `#render` is in the DOM:

```
var v = new BT.Common.FormTextArea({
    model: new Backbone.Model({text: 'init'}),
    el: '#render'
});

v.render();
```

and an updated Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/pCdSy/2/

Another solution would be to temporarily add your view `el` to the DOM, apply TinyMCE and then detach it.

```
var BT.Common.FormTextArea = Backbone.View.extend({
    template : template('form-input-textarea'),
    tagName: 'div',
    className: "control-group",

    initialize: function(){
    },

    render: function(){
        console.debug("Render FormTextArea");

        var html = this.template(this.model.toJSON());
        this.$el.html(html);    

        $('body').append(this.$el);   
        tinymce.init({selector: 'textarea'});
        this.$el.detach();

        return this;
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/pCdSy/4/ for a demo

Warning : this really looks like a hack and might produce unexpected results.

Comment: I have actually did not try your solution. It might be good. i am not accepting my answer, will see what the audience say :)

Answer (score 0):

I Solved it by creating an Iframe view and bringing small html code for the text area.

> ```
> BT.Common.IframeTextArea = Backbone.View.extend({
>     tagName: "div",
>     className: "row",
>     template : template('form-input-textarea'),
>     render: function(){
>         var html = this.template();
>         this.$el.html(html);
>         return this;
>     }
> });
> ```

and the template is just:

> ```
> <script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="form-input-textarea-template">
>     <div class="span12">
>       <iframe src="resources/textArea.html" style="width:100%;height:600px;border:0;padding:0"></iframe>
>     </div>
> </script>
> ```

and the textArea.html is:

> ```
> <script src="js-frameworks/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript">
> tinymce.init({
> selector: "textarea",
> plugins: [
>     "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
>     "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
>     "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
> ],
> toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright
>      alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"});
>   </script>
>   <textarea name="content" style="width:100%"></textarea>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

When rendering (Backbone.View.render), the el isn't inserted in the dom yet. Also, it is impossible to catch the moment when the view's el will be inserted in the dom. But a thing that is sure, is that at the end of the current browser's process, the el will be inserted in the DOM. Then tinyMCE will be "initializable". Simply wait 1 millisecond using "setTimeout" :

```
var FormTextArea = Backbone.View.extend({
    template : _.template('<%=value%>'),
    tagName: 'textarea',
    className: "control-group",
    render: function(){ 
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        setTimeout(_.bind(this.initMCE, this), 1);
        return this;
    },
    initMCE: function(){
        tinymce.init({selector: 'textarea'});
    }
});

var v = new FormTextArea({
    model: new Backbone.Model({value: '<h2>Heading 2</h2><p>A paragraph here</p>'})
});

$('body').append(v.render().el);
```

The jsfiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/pCdSy/10/